# How to write an xml attribute without replace all attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using this:

```
public void WriteSettings(string key, string value)
{
    XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xmlSettings.Indent = true;
    xmlSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(TMP_FULLPATH, xmlSettings);
    writer.WriteStartElement("settings");
    writer.WriteAttributeString(key, value);
    writer.WriteEndAttribute();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

But any modification replaces all attributes with only the last remaining attribute that I am trying to add. For example:

current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings TitleFormat="name:%name% date:%date%" />
```

when I do:

```
WriteSettings("foo", "baa");
```

the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings foo="baa" />
```

instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings TitleFormat="name:%name% date:%date%" foo="baa" />
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a new file, with no consideration at all of the old. To *update* a document, you must load it into a DOM, edit the DOM, and save the DOM:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute(key, value);
doc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are creating new file each time you call `XmlWriter.Create()`, do something like [this](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code143-adding-new-attribute-to-xml-file-in-csharp.aspx).